# Can getStaticProps() use .then syntax in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am reading the Next.js documentation and see the following example for using `getStaticProps()`

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Get external data from the file system, API, DB, etc.
  const data = ...

  // The value of the `props` key will be
  //  passed to the `Home` component
  return {
    props: ...
  }
}
```

Wherever I look, I've only see `export async function getStaticProps()` despite the fact that Promises with `.then` syntax should work just as well. Does Next enforce the `async/await` syntax or is it possible to use chained Promises with `.then`?

Comment: async/await is "syntax sugar" on top of `.then`.

Comment: I get that I'm just wondering why I've literally never seen Promise chaining with Next.js with `getStaticProps()`

Comment: It's probably because it's cleaner and easier to write it using async/await?

Comment: Oh ok, I just wanted to make sure the Next framework wasn't searching for the `async` keyword

Comment: You could try re-writing it in `.then` style and see if next complains?

Comment: I don't thik so. Next JS serialize the returning props, so if you return something using `.then` then it returns a promise and promise could not be serialized.

Comment: BTW, why do you need to use `.then` while Next allow you to use `await`?

Comment: I was just curious. Only the returned props are serialized so I don't think that should affect anything.

Comment: _"despite the fact that Promises with `.then` syntax should work just as well"_ - They do work just as well, why wouldn't they? Do you have a concrete example that doesn't work? `getStaticProps` already returns a promise, it's an async function.